# How to get number of user connections to app by week

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

(I am not a professional developer and I would need some help.)

I would like to get the number of user connections to my app by week, that means the number of times the user launched the app by week(max. 1 connection by day).

But the problem is that I don't know how to do this. I don't have any code.

I would like to know that number in order to rate the user activity on the app.

It seems complicated and I would be glad to have some help from someone more skilled than me.

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can see this automatically in iTunes connect/Play store when you release your app.

Other options would be to use firebase analytics to get some insights
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/